# No option to enable a camera in "sudo raspi-config"

Tags: pi-3, camera

[image]I would like to enable my camera in my Raspberry.

But when I go to `sudo raspi-config`, I don't have an option to enable/disable my camera.
I've already tried to upgrade and reboot my Pi, but it doesn't seem to work.

Anyone who could help me out?

Comment: I am assuming you mean a Pi-cam?

Comment: Could you show your `raspi-config` menu screen? Screenshot or a photo.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange network.  You say you've already tried to upgrade, do you literally mean just `sudo apt-get upgrade` or did you mean `sudo apt-get update` - the former means the bigger step to go from one version of (presumably) Raspbian to another which does not happen very often whereas the latter means the smaller step to make sure to get the latest updated versions for the current version of the Distribution and is probably more likely to produce some action...!

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot of my sudo raspi-config,

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of 5 and 7 interfacing and advanced options. The camera is likely under number 5 which you can get to by using the arrow keys on the keyboard. and the enter key to select.

Comment: the option is under 5 > P1

Answer (score 17):

The option to enable the camera is in the "Interfacing Options" submenu.  It will be clearly labelled ("Enable/disable connection to the Raspberry Pi Camera").

Answer (score 3):

You will find the enable camera option in interfacing options.Thanks